# How to safely modify in memory mongoid model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using mongoid gem on rail project and I'm quite puzzled by trying to modify the model in memory but never saving it so I do not modify the db. I'm trying to modify an attribute from a model loaded in memory but it does not work as shown bellow:

```
mymodel = MyModel.where('some criteria')
mymodel.first.some_attribute = 0
mymodel.first.some_attribute == 0 -> is false
```

So I guess mongo reloads from the db each time we do first or even looping on each entry and setting some attribute has no effect, if I loop again all attributes I set are still set to the original value. Is there a way to commit the transaction and force mymodel to stay loaded in memory? It's hard for me to use proper terminology so I hope you get what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `first` is a query so this is two distinct queries:

```
M.first
M.first
```

and two hits to the database that produce two completely different model instances. Similarly, calling `M.each { ... }` (or some other iteration method) twice will hit the database twice and produce two sets of completely distinct model instances. You could have a look at what `#object_id` says to verify this.

If you want to load the objects and do things to them then be explicit about it:

```
m = M.first
m.attr = 0
# Now m.attr == 0 will be true and you can m.save to update the database
```

and for iterating, you can call `#to_a` to execute the query and pull a bunch of model instances from the database into local memory:

ms = M.some_query.to_a
   ms.each { ... }
   ms.each { ... } # iterates over the same model instances as the first ms.each

Comment: Thx, that was my observation but I thought that doing ms = M.where('some criteria'); ms.each {...} would iterate over the instances of the query but it's not yet resolved and the query is executed each time.

Comment: `ms` would just be a query in that case and `ms.each { ... }` doesn't auto-resolve-and-stash the query, it simply executes the query and iterates over the results like a cursor; I have seen this cause interesting results if you're modifying while iterating (`ms.each { |m| m.attr = 6; m.save }` for example) unless you have an explicit ordering that's constant throughout the iteration.